# How to bind my Id value from XAML UI to ViewModel

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm new to Xamarin Forms, I am trying to get/Pass the Id value from XAML UI to my ViewModel

My XAML:

```
TODO
```

My VM:

```
 private int id;
        public int Id
        {
            get
            {
                return id;
            }
            set
            {
                if (id != value)
                {
                    id = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Id");
                }
            }
        }

        public string result { get; set; }

        public ICommand SubmitResultsCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command(async () =>
               {
                   IsLoading = true;

                   Result _result = new Result();

                   var response
                   = await _services.SubmitResultsAsync(result, id, Settings.AccessToken);

                   IsLoading = false;


               });
            }
        }
```

Comment: Since you had bound the value , you could define the Id in ViewModel directly instead of pass it .

Comment: Hi Lucas, Define it View Model like: int Id = ??; Please Elaboarate with Simple Example Please

Comment: Hi Lucas, i just Implemented the Code u shared me exactly as it is, but Still When i Debug, the Id Value Comes as Zero(0)

Comment: Please look on the Command button Code With Some Parameters in it

Comment: You need to post the full code .

Comment: Will do Shortly

Comment: Lucas, i just pasted my View model Code, together with the Code For Id u Shared with me, please Guide me, Based on that "SubmitResultsCommand" button, How to Access the Id Value From The UI , Please respond

Comment: I thought i can only Accept your Answer when my problem is resolved

Comment: Accepted your Answer

Comment: If you have more question you could create a new thread  :)

Comment: Trying to Post my XAML Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### in ViewModel

Define the binding property which you need to bind to view in xaml

```
public class MyViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        // it is necessary if you want to change the value of Id in runtime
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private string id;
        public string Id
        {
            get
            {
                return id;
            }
            set
            {
                if (id != value)
                {
                    id = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Id");
                }
            }
        }

        // other properties
    }
```

#### In ContentPage

Set the **BindingContext**

```
public MainPage()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   BindingContext = new MyViewModel();

}
```